# Do I need multiple copies of documents if we as a group are visiting Netherlands?

Tags: schengen, family

I (Indian) plan to visit Europe for tourism along with 3 family members. So, we have booked all the hotel reservations, flight tickets and train tickets together. Since our first entry country is the Netherlands, we are applying for Netherlands Visa.

In the visa portal (VFSGlobal) instruction, it says -

> All applicants traveling must apply in person at the visa application center.

Does this mean that we will need to create 4 copies of hotel reservations, train tickets, round-trip flights and other documents so that we can apply individually?

Comment: What does it say in the ‘documents required’ information for the VFS centre to which you’re applying? Are all travellers adults? Parents & minor children?

Comment: For me, "in person" doesn't imply one at a time; it rather means that e.g. you cannot act on behalf of your absent family members. Sounds more like you should preferably arrive as a group with (one copy of) your group travel documents (and of course your individual documents such as passports).

Comment: One comment: you should apply for a Schengen visa from the country that is your main (longest) purpose of visit. Traveling around makes this quite complicated. But if you only fly into The Netherlands and connect to say France and stay there for a week, then fly back out (either through The Netherlands or direct) then you should apply to France for a visa.

Comment: @Traveller Yes, all are adults.

Comment: @PaulPalmpje We are staying in the Netherlands for 2 days and staying in Switzerland which is our 3rd country for 3 days. Does that mean we should apply for a Swiss visa (even though the difference in stay is small)? I haven't read any official instructions regarding this so I don't know where this comes from.

Comment: @Avi You must apply to Switzerland https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf#page19 s2.1.2 “If the travel destination includes more than one Member State, the application must be dealt with by the consulate of the main destination. The main destination is understood to be the destination where the applicant intends to spend the longest time or where the main purpose of the intended journey is carried out.”

Comment: @Traveller Thank you. That does seem to be the case (I asked VFSGlobal).

Comment: @Avi Good to know VFS confirmed the information in the official European Commission visa handbook site I linked to is correct